# Dynamic PHP object access differs on local and server

Tags: php, json, post

On an local XAMPP development environment I can access an object's property in PHP by calling: 
`$xmltemplates->$_POST['xmlmap']->sheet;`

But on a live server I have to put the POST variable into a string so it works:

`$gehmiraufdiekeks = $_POST['xmlmap'];
$xmltemplates->$gehmiraufdiekeks->sheet;`

Do I need to fix alle the code or could it be a server configuration issue?

**UPDATE:**
I expected the XAMPP test environment to be at least PHP 7. So I only checked the server's PHP version which was 7. But when I doubled checked both PHP Infos, my local PHP version was 5.6. D'oh! So anyone who has this kind of problem: please update your code to PHP 7. ;)

Comment: different server configurations may be? different php versions

Comment: thanks, that's it exactly!

Comment: Your update should be posted as an Answer, not added to the question. You are allowed to answer your own question. The solution, fairly obviously, should not be part of the description of the original problem. Plus if you add an answer, others who find it useful can then upvote it, so it's in your interests to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Production servers are configured (or should be) to hide error messages. That's why you're getting none. You need to either check the server logs or enable full error reporting.
2. I understand you refer to invoking variable properties without using curly braces, as in:

   ```
   $key = 'bar';
   var_dump($foo->$bar);
   ```

   ... rather than:

   ```
   var_dump($foo->{$bar});
   ```

   That's explained in the [Changes to the handling of indirect variables, properties, and methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect) section of the PHP/7.0 migration guide (emphasis mine):

   > Indirect access to variables, properties, and methods will now be evaluated strictly in left-to-right order, as opposed to the previous mix of special cases.
   > [...]
   >   **Code that used the old right-to-left evaluation order must be rewritten to explicitly use that evaluation order with curly braces** (see the above middle column). This will make the code both forwards compatible with PHP 7.x and backwards compatible with PHP 5.x.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is PHP version related. They changed this in PHP 7 so no one can mess up your script with a wrecked, unescaped string sent via POST forms.